# GPS_PROVIDER всегда null

Tags: android, gps

Столкнулся с одной проблемой, и уже давно не могу решить ее. 
В приложении есть функция, которая строго по определенному времени снимает координаты пользователя. Вызывается она так:

```
public static HashMap<String, String> getMyLocation(boolean isManual, Context context) {

        LocationGetter locationGetter = new LocationGetter(context);

        HashMap<String, String> geoMap = locationGetter.getLocation(20000, 1000);
        String getWay = geoMap.get("location_get_way");
        if (getWay.equals("unknown")
                && isManual) {
            showSettingsAlert(context);
        }

        return geoMap;
    }
```

Вот еще 2 задействующих класса:

```
public class LocationGetter {

    private final Context context;
    private Location location = null;
    private final Object gotLocationLock = new Object();
    private final LocationResolver.LocationResult locationResult = new LocationResolver.LocationResult() {
        @Override
        public void gotLocation(Location location) {
            synchronized (gotLocationLock) {
                LocationGetter.this.location = location;
                gotLocationLock.notifyAll();
                Looper.myLooper().quit();
            }
        }
    };

    public LocationGetter(Context context) {
        if (context == null)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("context == null");

        this.context = context;
    }

    public synchronized HashMap<String, String> getLocation(int maxWaitingTime, int updateTimeout) {

        HashMap<String, String> geoMap = new HashMap<>();

        try {
            final int updateTimeoutPar = updateTimeout;
            synchronized (gotLocationLock) {
                new Thread() {
                    public void run() {
                        Looper.prepare();
                        LocationResolver locationResolver = new LocationResolver();
                        locationResolver.prepare();
                        locationResolver.getLocation(context, locationResult, updateTimeoutPar);
                        Looper.loop();
                    }
                }.start();

                gotLocationLock.wait(maxWaitingTime);
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        if (location != null) {
            String latitude = String.valueOf(location.getLatitude());
            String longitude = String.valueOf(location.getLongitude());
            String accuracy = String.valueOf(Math.round(location.getAccuracy()));
            geoMap.put("latitude", latitude);
            geoMap.put("longitude", longitude);
            geoMap.put("accuracy", accuracy);
            geoMap.put("location_get_way", location.getProvider());
        } else {
            geoMap.put("latitude", "0.0");
            geoMap.put("longitude", "0.0");
            geoMap.put("accuracy", "0.0");
            geoMap.put("location_get_way", "unknown");
        }
        return geoMap;
    }
}
```

и

```
public class LocationResolver {
    private Timer timer;
    private LocationManager locationManager;
    private LocationResult locationResult;
    private boolean gpsEnabled = false;
    private boolean networkEnabled = false;
    private Handler locationTimeoutHandler;

    private final Handler.Callback locationTimeoutCallback = new Handler.Callback() {
        public boolean handleMessage(Message msg) {
            locationTimeoutFunc();
            return true;
        }

        private void locationTimeoutFunc() {
            locationManager.removeUpdates(locationListenerGps);
            locationManager.removeUpdates(locationListenerNetwork);

            Location networkLocation = null, gpsLocation = null;             

            if (gpsEnabled)
                gpsLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
            if (networkEnabled)
                networkLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

            if (gpsLocation != null && networkLocation != null) {
                if (gpsLocation.getTime() > networkLocation.getTime())
                    locationResult.gotLocation(gpsLocation);
                else
                    locationResult.gotLocation(networkLocation);
                return;
            }

            if (gpsLocation != null) {
                locationResult.gotLocation(gpsLocation);
                return;
            }
            if (networkLocation != null) {
                locationResult.gotLocation(networkLocation);
                return;
            }
            locationResult.gotLocation(null);
        }
    };
    private final LocationListener locationListenerGps = new LocationListener() {
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            timer.cancel();
            locationResult.gotLocation(location);
            locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
            locationManager.removeUpdates(locationListenerNetwork);
        }

        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        }

        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        }

        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        }
    };
    private final LocationListener locationListenerNetwork = new LocationListener() {
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            timer.cancel();
            locationResult.gotLocation(location);
            locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
            locationManager.removeUpdates(locationListenerGps);
        }

        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        }

        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        }

        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        }
    };

    public void prepare() {
        locationTimeoutHandler = new Handler(locationTimeoutCallback);
    }

    public synchronized boolean getLocation(Context context, LocationResult result, int maxMillisToWait) {
        locationResult = result;
        if (locationManager == null)
            locationManager = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        try {
            gpsEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
        }
        try {
            networkEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
        }

        if (!gpsEnabled && !networkEnabled)
            return false;

        if (gpsEnabled)
            locationManager.requestSingleUpdate(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, locationListenerGps, Looper.myLooper());
        if (networkEnabled)
            locationManager.requestSingleUpdate(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, locationListenerNetwork, Looper.myLooper());

        timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(new GetLastLocationTask(), maxMillisToWait);
        return true;
    }

    private class GetLastLocationTask extends TimerTask {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            locationTimeoutHandler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
        }
    }

    public static abstract class LocationResult {
        public abstract void gotLocation(Location location);
    }
}
```

Собственно проблема в том, что мой `gpsLocation` абсолютно всегда приходит null. Будь то девайс в оффисе или на улице- без разницы. Данные всегда снимаются только с помощью NETWORK_PROVIDER и не всегда корректно. Пермишны в манифесте все имеются. 
Буду рад любому совету!

Answer (score 1):

Не вдавался в подробности кода, потому что понаписано много и большая часть из этого, простите, мусор

Координаты нельзя снять в строго определенное время. Провайдер сам снимает координаты исходя из параметров которые вы ему задали (расстояние, время).

В двух словах это делается так: вы создаете **LocationListener**, который имеет метод **onLocationChanged**. Этот метод - это callback функция, которая срабатывает каждый раз когда меняется позиция.

Если не получается сделать так, чтоб координаты обрабатывались в этом методе, тогда вы можете создать статичную переменную координат и считывать ее в строго определенное время. А провайдер, в свою очередь, будет туда сам периодически класть новые координаты.

Работу с это статичной переменной вы можете обвернуть в блок синхронизации.

В итоге ваш код будет раза в 4 проще.